# How can I parse a Database most efficiently from C# to Python?

Tags: c#, python, xml

I want to parse a DataBase that has been acquired with C# (Unity3D Project) to Python. I looked around for information on how to read serialized classes from C# in Python, but was unsuccesful with it, and I haven't found any good information on how to read XML files in Python. 
I messed around with IronPython, but wasn't able to get it to work.

It might be important to know that Unity still uses .NET 2.0...

I'm a total noob in this domain, but it's really essential to let these two languages communicate with each other...

Comment: What does "DataBase" mean exactly in this context?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It would be a class containing a couple of large Arrays.

Comment: Have you seen this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34662448/net-c-interop-to-python