# Call C# function inside compiled exe using Python

Tags: c#, python-3.x, code-injection

Hey guys so I have a compiled exe written in C#, is there any way I could call methods and functions inside the exe using a python script?

The exe is reverse engineered using ILSpy and I know the functions name so I know their locations and what to call.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
public static class Program
{
    public const bool IsServer = true;

    public static Dictionary<string, string> LaunchParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public static void LaunchGame(string[] args)
    {
        LaunchParameters = Utils.ParseArguements(args);
        using Main main = new Main();
        try
        {
            SocialAPI.Initialize();
            LaunchInitializer.LoadParameters(main);
            main.DedServ();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            DisplayException(e);
        }
    }

    private static void DisplayException(Exception e)
    {
        try
        {
            using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter("client-crashlog.txt", append: true))
            {
                streamWriter.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
                streamWriter.WriteLine(e);
                streamWriter.WriteLine("");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Server crash: " + DateTime.Now);
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Please send crashlog.txt to support@terraria.org");
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is to call the `LaunchGame()` method of the above class from a python script.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.NET/C# Interop to Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34662448/net-c-interop-to-python)

Comment: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet